# Uninstalling django-dagging-autocomplete

Tags: django, django-tagging

I've used setuptools to install **django-tagging-autocpmlete**. I then added all necessary settings to the settings file (INSTALLED_APPS, etc) and it worked fine.

When I wanted to remove the app, I took it off my INSTALLED_APPS list. The problem is that now I get

> TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
>   "Caught ValueError while rendering:
>   Empty module name"

when trying to access my admin panel.
What can cause this problem?

Thanks,

Meir

Comment: Have you removed any other setting relating to the app? Specifically anything that alters how the admin is rendered?